# How to run the queries written in the command line using neo4j-shell?

Tags: neo4j

I am using Mac OS. I want to use neo4j-shell to write my queries and run them to create my database. Therefore, I ran the command ./bin/neo4j-shell
After I write my queries, what should I type to run the queries? Because though I keep pressing enter, it just goes to the next line and doesn't run the query.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you should add a ";" after the query to commit them

Comment: Thank you very much Christophe :)